# Categorical variable from continuous variable: should I aim for the same number of observations?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, categorical-data

I am converting a continuous variable to a categorical variable with the aim to use it as a factor in an ANOVA test. Having to decide if each level of the factor will include the same number of observation of it is better to have levels equally spaced I would ask the community. Any idea?

Comment: Why convert it at all? What problem do you think that will solve?

Comment: I want to test if my dependent variable was influenced by factors like latitude, longitude or altitude. I thought that making them categorical dividing the space in areas and find if a range of latitudes longitudes etc could influence the dependent variable. Does it make any sense?

Comment: I see no reason there to categorize. That would be just throwing away information.  Very possibly your unstated dependent variable varies nonlinearly with location, but the implication there is a different functional form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. My variable in this case is the content of glucose in the cell wall of different species of grass. I expect (according to literature) this variable being not linear along the three above mentioned factors. Do you believe I should keep it as it is? Can I run an ANOVA using those as factors or should I rather do a correlation analysis?

Comment: I don't have any beliefs on what you should do without looking at the data. Preliminary plotting of the data against latitude, longitude and altitude should help. There could be enormous difference in what makes sense ranging from your data being a collation of data from around the world to them being for a much smaller region. But if you think relationships are not linear there is no rationale to just including them in analyses as they are.